# Multi input Functional API CNN model

Tags: keras, functional-api

1. I am making multi input cnn model using keras functional api but it
   is giving error... data:

   ```
    trainset1 = trainset.flow_from_directory(
       '/content/',
       target_size=(404,410),
       batch_size=32,
       #seed=50,
       class_mode='categorical') print('In Training Set..Entropy....') trainset12 = trainset.flow_from_directory(
       '/content/',
       target_size=(404,410),
       batch_size=32,
       #seed=50,
       class_mode='categorical')
   ```

   model: input1 = Input(shape=(404,410,3)) input2 = Input(shape =
   (404,410,3))

   ```
   # x = layers.Dense(128, activation= 'relu')
   ```

   x = layers.Conv2D(25, (5, 5), activation='relu',
   padding='same')(input1) x = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2),
   padding='same')(x)

   x1 = layers.Conv2D(25, (5, 5), activation='relu',
   padding='same')(input2) x1 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2),
   padding='same')(x1) flat_layer1 = Flatten()(x) flat_layer2 =
   Flatten()(x1)

   ## print(flat_layer1.shape)

   ## print(flat_layer2.shape) concat_layer= Concatenate()([flat_layer1,flat_layer2])

   ## concat_layer= concatenate([flat_layer1,flat_layer2])

   ## x = layers.Dense(16, activation= 'relu')(flat_layer1)     #(concat_layer) outputs = layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')(concat_layer) model =

   keras.Model(inputs=[input1,input2], outputs = outputs)

   model.compile(
   loss = keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
   optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
   metrics=["accuracy"] )

   model.fit([trainset1,trainset12] ,batch_size=32,epochs=5, verbose=2)

   GIVING ERROR:

   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent
   call last)  in ()
   ----> 1 model.fit([trainset1,trainset12] ,batch_size=32,epochs=5, verbose=2)

   1 frames
   /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py
   in select_data_adapter(x, y)
   989         "Failed to find data adapter that can handle "
   990         "input: {}, {}".format(
   --> 991             _type_name(x), _type_name(y)))
   992   elif len(adapter_cls) > 1:
   993     raise RuntimeError(

   ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input:
   (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class
   'keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator'>"}), <class
   'NoneType'`"""`

   what should i do now?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to make custom imagedatagenerator function by which I can give multiple input into functional cnn model...